# PCB design issues for handling 50A current

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, heat, high-current, power-dissipation

I am working on a *combiner circuit* that will monitor the current and voltage rating of my device. The device and **the combiner must handle 50A Current**. Im using a shunt on my combiner PCB to measure the voltage/current. Now while testing as I increased the current supplied above 20 25 A, the PCB track started to melt and smoke up. Im using a 2oz thickness and a pretty wide track. Are there any ways to **manage heat dissipation or even generation**(Im measuring Current, so the only parameter that I can control at source is resistance. While beyond a limit isnt the best solution)

Comment: How wide is "pretty wide"?

Comment: I am guessing not the ~80-100mm that is required for that kind of current...

Comment: Online tools for this sort of thing are your friend; consult them for guidance early: http://www.4pcb.com/trace-width-calculator.html

Comment: https://www.saturnpcb.com/pcb_toolkit.htm should be installed on everyones machine

Comment: Have you considered adding extra copper in parallel with the PCB tracks? I have worked with both separate bus bars and simple wire links in a track. Note: The resistance of solder is much higher than than copper so the benefit of covering bare tracks with solder is minimal.

Comment: @WarrenHill Electrically minimal. It does add thermal mass though which can be beneficial.

Comment: I would use an external current shunt - keeping the 50 Amps off the PC board - and just run sense leads from the shunt to the board.

Comment: I concur with Warren and Peter.  Taking these parts off the board or adding substantial power bus is likely the best way.  Also check what others have done - https://www.google.com/search?q=50A+current+shunt+PCB&source=lnms&tbm=isch

Answer (score 1):

For 50 A with a copper busbar of 1.3 mm square results in a 10'C internal rise.

Larger is recommend for minimal drop in voltage or other materials or lower temp rise.